# Windows installation (7, 8.1 and 10) fails on custom built new computer

Tags: windows, installation

I have just built a new computer, and I am now trying to install Windows on it, but it dosent seems to work at all. Here are my system specs:

- **Mobo:** [MSI A88X-G41 V2](http://us.msi.com/product/mb/A88X-G41-PC-Mate.html)
- **CPU:** AMD A10 6700
- **RAM:** 8GB HyperX Fury 1600Mhz
- **GPU:** ASUS GTX 680

I’ve tried Windows 7, but it just throws an `0x80070015` error code in after the files have been copied.

Then I tried Windows 8.1, which didn’t get further than the Windows logo, and the same with Windows 10. I really don’t know what to do.

Comment: Apparently (from some quick googling), error 0x80070015 is some variation on "files missing". Double-check that your installation media is good. If you can, also put the hard disk from the new system into a different system (or boot from a live CD or similar) and run a SMART long self-test (and let it run to completion; this can take several hours), then look at the results of that.

Comment: You might also try to boot from a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 15, to help determine if its a hardware issue or driver issue... Ubuntu and others are good about booting with limited drivers, and finding alternatives on the web, once booted. If Linux works, then your Windows install media could be at fault or incompatible with UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

the 0x80070015 error usually means a disk (hard) problem, you should delete all your partition an create a new one. 
you can do that via CMD commands (dos)
diskpart  (will run diskpart.exe)
list disk
select disk 0
then select and delete partition
if you have more than 1 partition delete them as well
then :  create partition primary
if your problem is not solved do a check disk on cmd
chkdsk /f /r